# Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be three times differentiable. Determine constants $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be three times differentiable with $f'''(x)$ bounded. Determine constants $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$f''(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{af(x-h)+bf(x)+cf(x+2h)}{h^2}$

I was trying to think of how to do this, and all I can think of is that maybe L'Hopital or using Taylor's Formula, but I have no idea if those work or where to go from there.

Edit:

Using the Taylor series expansions of $f(x+h)$ and $f(x-h)$,

> $$ f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x)h+f''(x)\frac{h^2}{2} + f'''(x)\frac{h^3}{3!}+\cdots $$
>
> $$ f(x-h) = f(x) - f'(x)h+f''(x)\frac{h^2}{2} - f'''(x)\frac{h^3}{3!}+\cdots  $$

Adding the above equations gives

> $$   \frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h)}{h^2} =  f''(x) + 2\frac{f''''(x)}{4!}h^2+\cdots $$

taking the limit of the above equation as $h$ goes to zero gives the desired result

> $$ \Rightarrow f''(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h)}{h^2} \,.$$

I'm now stuck again. I would appreciate any additional assistance. I'm not certain how to proceed from here to apply the other parts of my problem. Specifically, I'm not sure about how to ensure my choices of $a,b,c$ allow for $f'''(x)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 4):

Taylor Series seems fine
$$ f(x+2h) = f(x) + 2f'(x)h+2f''(x)h^2 + 8f'''(x)\frac{h^3}{3!}+\cdots $$
$$ 2f(x-h) = 2f(x) - 2f'(x)h+f''(x) h^2 - 2f'''(x)\frac{h^3}{3!}+\cdots  $$ 
$$   \frac{f(x+2h) - 3f(x) + 2f(x-h)}{h^2} =  3f''(x) + 6 f'''(x)h+\cdots $$

taking the limit 
$$ \Rightarrow f''(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\frac{1}{3}f(x+2h) - f(x) + \frac{2}{3}f(x-h)}{h^2} \,.$$

The next step could be to use the constants in epsilon inequalities

Comment: Do you think I could use what you just did to solve for $f'''$ instead of $f''$ and get something useful from that?

Comment: It is not possible to express f'''(x) being divided by h ^ 2. It could be divided by h ^ 3. This fact can be demonstrated using asymptotic notation. You might want to check "numerical differentiation".

Comment: @MC989:  you are looking for an expression for the second derivative, not the third.  Your question has it right, the left side is $f''(x)$

Comment: I'm looking for the $a,b,c$ that satisfy this and ensure that $f'''$ is bounded. I'm simply trying to figure out a way that I can ensure this holds.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Express $f''$ using the definition of a limit (using $f'$), and then substitute the limit definition of $f'$ into the expressions and simplify.

Comment: So then $f''(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f'(x+h)-f'(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{af(x-h)+bf(x)+cf(x+2h)}{h^2}$? Is that what you're trying to say?

Comment: I'm saying to keep what you have after the first I equality you just typed, then for every $f'$ plug in the limit of $\frac {f (x+h)-f (x)}{h}$

Comment: You will end up up with a difference of fractions with denominator $h$ over $h $, does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The question asserts that you can find $a,b,c$ for *all* functions that are three times differentiable.  You know that polynomials are infinitely differentiable, so let $f(x)=x^3+dx^2+ex+f$  Plug that in. $d,e,f$ have to cancel out, because this has to be true for all polynomials (among other functions).  That will give you three equations in $a,b,c$

Comment: Now how can I assure that $f'''$ will be bounded given my ultimate choices of $a,b,c$?